# Should Isolated Content appear in Sitemap for SEO purposes?

Tags: seo, xml-sitemap

I have a website with some content that I purposefully want to leave isolated (no incoming internal links) from the rest of the website.

I do however want SEO benefits from the content of these pages and want to include these in an XML sitemap for Google to crawl.

Would Google’s crawler have any issues with content that's included in the sitemap but is not reachable from anywhere in the rest of the website? Or is this okay?

Comment: See [The Sitemap Paradox](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/4803/the-sitemap-paradox):   Unless your content is linked, it won't rank well.  Even if you include it in your sitemap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one of the reasons sitemaps exists. So search engines can find content that they may normally not be able to find through the usual means (i.e. links). So, yes, put these pages in your sitemap.

Comment: Thanks! Just to be clear, isolated content is a-okay with Google and other search engines, no known penalties associated with it?

Comment: None. It happens and it's ok.

Comment: Great. Now [my parenting blog](http://paretoparenting.com) can enjoy some SEO love. Yay.

Comment: Just to confirm what John has said, my site consists mostly of pages that are not linked. It is not practical to link them all. Currently, there are over 550,000 pages not linked, however, they exist in my sitemap and are properly indexed in Google. It is the bulk of the site and enjoys appropriate performance in the SERPs without restriction.

Comment: "penalty", no.   But Google doesn't index content well unless that content also has links to it from somewhere.  See [The Sitemap Paradox](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/4803/the-sitemap-paradox).  If you want your content to rank well, a sitemap is not sufficient.  You must link to it from somewhere as well.